# Spring security issue

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

Dear All,
                     New is Spring Security. I have configured my server to check the login with Spring Security. Now I deployed it on some server and accessing it by domain name. I am able to access all the urls, except the SpringSecurity. Does it check the url also ?? How can I change it ??

```
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.do" access="fullyAuthenticated" />
    <form-login login-page="/index.do" always-use-default-target="false" default-target-url="/login.do" />
    <anonymous />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/index.do" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />
    <custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="springSocialSecurityAuthenticationFilter" />
    <remember-me services-ref="springSocialSecurityRememberMeServices" key="springSocialSecurity" />
</http>
```

Thanks,
OP

Comment: share your spring security configuration

Comment: I have updated my question with configuration. Please reply.

Comment: What version of Spring Security are you using?  You really need to provide as much information as possible.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in `intercept-url`, you have to write `access="isFullyAuthenticated()"`  or use the spring security constants : `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`

your declaration is `<intercept-url pattern="/login.do" access="fullyAuthenticated" />` 
Meaning that you have to be logged in for accessing the login.do page.

I don't think it is what you want.

here some examples of how `intercept-url` works:

```
    <intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="permitAll" />   
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/extreme/**" access="hasRole('supervisor')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/listAccounts.html" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/post.html" access="hasAnyRole('supervisor','regularuser')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
```

you have to define levels of authorization based on the url of your application. 
to access the login page, you need to let the login page be `permitAll` access... so the user can login.

if a user try to access a `isAuthenticated()` page without being logged in, there will be a redirection to the login page.

you can put multiple access to a pattern. For example, you can decide that a page could be accessed with authentification OR a anonymous role:

```
<intercept-url pattern='/page2.jsp' access='ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER'/>
```

Comment: Thanks Rigg for your kind help and detail info. My issue is when I access my application using the IP address it works fine. Something like this 222.222.222.222:8080/myApp, but when I access the same app with domain name. www.domain.com/211, it does not work. When I am hitting the url it redirect to apache server then tomcat server. If I keep the webapp name in the url, it works. But if I add some other name in url, does not work.

Comment: ok, I do not think it is a spring security problem. It probably come from server configuration. do you have a Apache server in the front that redirects to your Tomcat? do you use HTTPS? Do you use "url rewritting" ?

Comment: Yes thats true. I have an apache server that redirects to tomcat but ho HTTPS. Only HTTP. I use the below mentioned script to redirect.. ProxyPass /abc http://localhost:8080/xyz

Comment: That's what I thought. Take a look at 'mod_jk' instead. define your workers in a properties. The apache will communicate with your tomcat

Comment: What changes needed there. I did not work on the mod_jk before. Something new to me. Can you please give me some link or code. Will be a great help.